# How many could review Lisp, Scheme, or Racket?

Tags: discussion

For future reference, I would like to get an idea of how many people could review Lisp, Scheme, or Racket programs and code. Of course, my work will not be very advanced for some time yet.

Comment: One problem (someone with 150+ rep should fix this): The `common-lisp`, `scheme` and `racket` tags don't seem to exist yet. `elisp` exists because I had the presence of mind to submit a related question during the closed beta, but we may want to add these tags if we're to have more lisp questions.

Answer (score 4):

I could probably look them over (just had to google to see Racket is just PLT Scheme renamed).  Its been about 6 years, but I should be able to remember enough of it after looking at some code again.

Comment: Yes, renamed and improved, I understand.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an active scheme developer, but I think I'm confident enough with scheme to review most code, though I might miss the finer points of the language's coding conventions. I would certainly take a look at it.

You should definitely post it if you have something to be reviewed. I'd like to see more questions in some of the less common languages on this site.

On a somewhat discouraging note, I'm sad to see that [this elisp question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45/emacs-etags-shortcut-functions) is still unanswered after 12 days. Though I supposed elisp is a bit of a niche even as far as lisps go.

Answer (score 2):

I can read and understand it. I'm still a relative beginner (maybe low intermediate), but I believe I could at least give some ideas on how to improve the code. I'd let the voting determine just how good those ideas are, though :).

Answer (score 2):

Active common-lisper here (and I have experience with Racket and Elisp). I don't claim to be great, but I'm able and willing to read and comment on code in these languages.